# Override variables defined in lib.d.ts

Tags: typescript

I've got the typing below for WebWorkers API. In the very bottom of the file is a line that describes self object. The same variable name is used in lib.d.ts and when I add the reference to WebWorker.d.ts I see that self has type Window, not DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope.
What should I fix to override this definition ?

```
interface WorkerNavigator extends NavigatorID, NavigatorOnLine {
}

interface WorkerUtils extends WindowTimers, WindowBase64 {
    importScripts: (...urls: string[]) => void;
    navigator: WorkerNavigator;
}

interface WorkerLocation {
    href: string;
    protocol: string;
    host: string;
    hostname: string;
    port: string;
    pathname: string;
    search: string;
    hash: string;
}

interface WorkerGlobalScope extends EventTarget, WorkerUtils {
    self: WorkerGlobalScope;
    location: WorkerLocation;

    close: () => void;
    onerror: Function;
    onoffline: Function;
    ononline: Function;
}

interface DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope extends WorkerGlobalScope {
    postMessage:(message:any, ...args:any[])=>void;
    onmessage: Function;
}

declare var self: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope;
```

**UPD:**
Despite the code above, I have to use the following way. Looks like the definition of self wasn't overriden

```
/// <reference name="WebWorkers.d.ts" />

declare var self: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope;
```

Comment: TypeScript 0.9.1 in VS 2013 RC and this works fine for me...

Comment: It works, but I have to put `declare var self: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope;` everywhere when I use this typing

Answer (score 1):

That code is valid and you can see that it works with the latest version of <kbd>[TypeScript here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20WorkerNavigator%20extends%20NavigatorID,%20NavigatorOnLine%20%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20WorkerUtils%20extends%20WindowTimers,%20WindowBase64%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20importScripts%3a%20%28...urls%3a%20string%5B%5D%29%20=%3E%20void;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20navigator%3a%20WorkerNavigator;%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20WorkerLocation%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20href%3a%20string;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protocol%3a%20string;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20host%3a%20string;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20hostname%3a%20string;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20port%3a%20string;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20pathname%3a%20string;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20search%3a%20string;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20hash%3a%20string;%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20WorkerGlobalScope%20extends%20EventTarget,%20WorkerUtils%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20self%3a%20WorkerGlobalScope;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20location%3a%20WorkerLocation;%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20close%3a%20%28%29%20=%3E%20void;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20onerror%3a%20Function;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20onoffline%3a%20Function;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ononline%3a%20Function;%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope%20extends%20WorkerGlobalScope%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20postMessage%3a%28message%3aany,%20...args%3aany%5B%5D%29=%3Evoid;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20onmessage%3a%20Function;%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20self%3a%20DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope;)</kbd>

TypeScript interfaces are open ended :

```
interface Foo{
    bar:number;
}

// Continue to add members to Foo: 
interface Foo{
    baz: number;
}

// The followin is valid : 
var foo:Foo;
foo.bar = 123; 
foo.baz = 456;
```